# Android R.java - "overloading" values

Tags: android, overloading, r.java-file

I've searched for information about this but it's hard when I don't really know what to search for.

I'm working on a few android projects which share a common base (that I put in a few libs). The libs works with both classes and xml-files, and some other resources too. The most common is that I have a drawable xml which gets color information from an xml-file which defines which colors to use, called something like "foobar_colors.xml" or so. The "foobar_colors.xml" in the lib itself defines default colors.

When I use the lib in the projects these colors needs to change (to use the client company colors or so), and I'm not sure how the best way is to accomplish this... The libs uses allot of resorces, their own xml-layouts and such, so I really can't always "declare things stylable".

The way I do it now is include the "foobar" lib in my project, copy the "foobar_colors.xml" to my project resources and change their values there. This works since R.java seems to "overload" values like the lib itself sets "foobar_color1" to be black and the project sets it again to be red (and the projects defines has higher priority).

Now I'm just wondering, is this safe? Is there any better way to do it? Possible problems that might come up in the future?